# Unzipping subdirectories and files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression

I am trying to implement an unzipping feature in a project that I am currently working  on, but the problem is that I have some limitations when it comes to licening and I am required to stay away from GPL alike licenses, because the project is closed sourced.

So that means that I can no longer use SharpZipLib.. so I moved to .Net libraries
Currently I am trying to work with the ZipArchive library.

The problem is that it does not extract for directories/subdirectories, so if I have blabla.zip that has 
file.txt inside and /folder/file2.txt the whole thing will be extracted to file.txt and file2.txt, so it ignores the subdirectory.

I am using the example from MSDN website.
which looks something like:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
  foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
  {
    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
  } 
}
```

Any idea  how to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if your archive looks like this:

```
archive.zip
  file.txt
  someFolder
    file2.txt
```

then `entry.FullName` for file2.txt is `someFolder/file2.txt` so even your code will work normaly if the folder exists. So you can create it.

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!entry.Name.Equals("please dont extract me.txt"))
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

or you should better use static `ZipFile` method if you need to extract all the archive

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't know the content of my zip file that I am retrieving usually, so it could be txt or it could be something else.

Comment: So use `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);`

Comment: thanks, but how can I use such a statement 
`if (!entry.Name.Equals("Updater.exe"))
{
//start writing
}`
because the updater.exe is the one currently running and I don't want to interrupt it.

Comment: just insert this code before extraction. I have updated my answer

Comment: Doesn't work with some ZIP files created on a linux server (the entries with empty names do not show up). The Windows explorer extracts those files correctly though.

Comment: Why the odd `else { if (...) { ... } }`? Why not just `else if`?